# Video file has audio but video players don't see or play the audio

Tags: ios, swift, audio, video, avassetwriter

I have created a video file from an iPhone's camera/microphone using AVAssetWriter, AVAssetWriterInput, etc. and when I play the resulting video in iMovie, QuickTime player, and Davinci Resolve, there appears to be no audio. iMovie's audio waveform is empty, although the QuickTime inspector shows an audio track present.

However, I opened the same video file using Ocenaudio and it reads and plays the audio completely fine. So I know the audio is somewhere in the fie.

I used widely available code for using AVAssetWriter, such as:

```
previewVideoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: videoOutputSettings)
previewVideoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
previewAudioWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaType.audio, outputSettings: audioOutputSettings)
previewAudioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

if previewVideoWriter.canAdd(previewVideoWriterInput) == true { previewVideoWriter.add(previewVideoWriterInput) }
if previewVideoWriter.canAdd(previewAudioWriterInput) == true { previewVideoWriter.add(previewAudioWriterInput) }
```

The main difference is that I'm using a CIFilter on the video data in the captureOutput() function. Here's a simplified version of my captureOutout() code:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    recordingQueue.async {
        autoreleasepool {
            if output == self.previewVideoOutput {
                let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
                let cameraImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)
                if self.currentFilter != nil { self.currentFilter.setValue(cameraImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey) }
                let filteredImage = UIImage(ciImage: self.currentFilter != nil ? self.currentFilter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage : cameraImage)

                let timeStampie = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
                self.previewProgressTimeStamp = timeStampie
                if self.previewFirstFrameTimeStamp == CMTime.zero {
                    self.previewFirstFrameTimeStamp = self.previewProgressTimeStamp
                }
                self.previewProgressTimeStamp = CMTimeSubtract(self.previewProgressTimeStamp, self.previewFirstFrameTimeStamp)
                if self.previewVideoWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                    let appendSuccess = self.previewVideoAdapter.append(self.pixelBufferFromImage(filteredImage)!, withPresentationTime: self.previewProgressTimeStamp)
                }
            }
            else if output == self.previewAudioOutput {
                if self.previewAudioWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                    let appendSuccess = self.previewAudioWriterInput.append(sampleBuffer)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I use when it's time to finish recording:

```
if previewVideoWriterInput != nil {
    previewVideoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
    previewAudioWriterInput.markAsFinished()
}
if previewVideoWriter != nil {
    previewVideoWriter.endSession(atSourceTime: previewProgressTimeStamp)
    previewVideoWriter.finishWriting { () -> Void in
        self.recordingCompletedHandler?()
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the audio being written to the video file is not being seen by video players? And how would I fix that?

Edit:

Here's the code I'm using to setup the AVCapture outputs as requested.

```
captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
captureSession.beginConfiguration()

captureSession.sessionPreset = .vga640x480
captureSession.usesApplicationAudioSession = true

if frontCameraInput != nil && captureSession.canAddInput(frontCameraInput) == true { captureSession.addInput(frontCameraInput) }
if let audioCaptureDeviceInput = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio) { audioCaptureDevice = audioCaptureDeviceInput }
if audioCaptureDevice != nil {
    do {
        audioCaptureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioCaptureDevice)
    } catch let error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

if audioCaptureDeviceInput != nil && captureSession.canAddInput(audioCaptureDeviceInput) == true { captureSession.addInput(audioCaptureDeviceInput) }

previewVideoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: recordingQueue)
previewAudioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: recordingQueue)

if captureSession.canAddOutput(previewVideoOutput) { captureSession.addOutput(previewVideoOutput) }
if captureSession.canAddOutput(previewAudioOutput) { captureSession.addOutput(previewAudioOutput) }

captureSession.commitConfiguration()
```

Comment: Can you show how you're configuring `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput`?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman Thanks. I added the code above.